# python selecting by rotation from multiple lists

Tags: python, list, indexing

i have 4 lists as follows:

```
import numpy as np

file1 = np.arange(0, 4).tolist()
file2 = np.arange(3, 7).tolist()
file3 = np.arange(7, 11).tolist()
file4 = np.arange(11, 15).tolist()
```

and i want to select by rotation from each list and end up with a final set as follows:

```
final = {0, 4, 9, 14}
```

i have a solution that does work but i am wondering if there is an easier method or a more pythonic way to do this?

```
def get_rotated(file1: list,
                         file2: list,
                         file3: list,
                         file4: list):
    count = 0
    i = 0    
    final = set()    
    while i < (get_len(file1) -1):
        print('here')
        if count == 0:
            print(i)
            tag = file1[i]
            count+=1
            final.add(tag)
            i += 1
        if count == 1:
            print(i)

            tag = file2[i]
            count+=1
            final.add(tag)
            i += 1
        if count == 2:
            print(i)
            tag = file3[i]
            count+=1
            final.add(tag)
            i += 1    
        if count == 3:
            print(i)
            tag = file4[i]
            count=0
            final.add(tag)
            i += 1
    return final
```

this returns the correct set {0, 4, 9, 14}. I want this to keep rotating the selection in groups if the list size was bigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a list of lists and pick the item corresponding to each list's position in the list of lists:

```
[ L[i] for i,L in enumerate([file1,file2,file3,file4]) ]

[0, 4, 9, 14]
```

**Multiple cycles:** *(full rotations)*

If you have longer lists you can place the list of the lists in a variable, and have it go more than one cycle by multiplying the list of lists by the number of cycles (full rotations):

```
file1 = list(range(0, 14))
file2 = list(range(3, 17))
file3 = list(range(7, 21))
file4 = list(range(11, 25))

files  = [file1,file2,file3,file4]
cycles = min(map(len,files))//len(files)
r = [ L[i] for i,L in enumerate(files*cycles) ]

print(r)
[0, 4, 9, 14, 4, 8, 13, 18, 8, 12, 17, 22]
```

As a set:

```
r = { L[i] for i,L in enumerate(files*rotations) }
print(r)
{0, 4, 8, 9, 12, 13, 14, 17, 18, 22}
```

**Multiple rotations** *(including partial rotations)*

If you need to allow for partial rotations at the end of the sequence, you can use modulo indexing over the tuples produced by zip():

```
files = [file1,file2,file3,file4]
r = [T[i%len(files)] for i,T in enumerate(zip(*files))]

print(r)
[0, 4, 9, 14, 4, 8, 13, 18, 8, 12, 17, 22, 12, 16]
```

This picks up two more items from file1 and file2:

```
                                                                  partial
                                                                 |--------|    
file1: [0]   1    2    3   [4]   5    6    7   [8]   9   10   11  [12] 13
file2:  3   [4]   5    6    7   [8]   9   10   11  [12]  13   14   15 [16]
file3:  7    8   [9]  10   11   12  [13]  14   15   16  [17]  18   19  20
file4: 11   12   13  [14]  15   16   17  [18]  19   20   21  [22]  23  24
```

As a set:

```
r = {T[i%len(files)] for i,T in enumerate(zip(*files))}

print(r)
{0, 4, 8, 9, 12, 13, 14, 16, 17, 18, 22}
```

*This zip() approach would also work if your input is composed of iterators (e.g. actual files) as it doesn't use any indexing on the data itself. It also makes it easy to offset the rotations using the second parameter of enumerate().*

**A more "Pythonic" function:**

Your complete function could look more "Pythonic" like this:

```
def get_rotated(*files):
    return { T[i%len(files)] for i,T in enumerate(zip(*files)) }
```

Since your output is going to be a set, you can streamline this using a nested comprehension that combines a striding subscript of each list offset by 1 per list (given that the order of the values won't matter):

```
def get_rotated(*files):
    return {n  for i,f in enumerate(files) for n in f[i::len(files)]}
```

or (for only 4 lists):

```
def get_rotated(file1,file2,file3,file4):
    return {*file1[::4], *file2[1::4], *file3[2::4], *file4[3::4]}
```

Comment: This works for this small example set but it doesn't work for a larger set where each file has more than 4 numbers.

Comment: I missed the requirement for multiple rotations in the question.  Adjusted my answer accordingly, including a variant to allow for partial rotations at the end of the sequence.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you need. You should use list names like below via iterating

```
import numpy as np

file1 = np.arange(0, 4).tolist()
file2 = np.arange(3, 7).tolist()
file3 = np.arange(7, 11).tolist()
file4 = np.arange(11, 15).tolist()

countOfLists = 4
finalList = []
for i in range(1, countOfLists + 1):
    finalList.append(globals()['file%s'%i][i - 1])
print(finalList)
```

Comment: i think this is what i need based on your example. `countOfLists = 4
finalList = []
total = get_len(file1) -1
row_count=0
while row_count <=total:
    for i in range(1, countOfLists + 1):
        finalList.append(globals()['file%s'%i][row_count])
        row_count+=1
    
print(finalList)`

Comment: no that's wrong!

Comment: @meltedhead What do you want exactly? your code prints `[0, 3, 7, 11, 1, 4, 8, 12, 2, 5, 9, 13, 3, 6, 10, 14]`

Comment: @meltedhead I thought that you want f`1st` lists `1st` element,`2nd` lists `2nd` element, `3rd` lists `3rd` element, `4th` lists `4th element and so on....